# c# Selenium EdgeOptions not working for Chromium Edge

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have chromium edge version 80.0.361.69. For this, I am using Selenium.WebDriver -Version 4.0.0-alpha05. The testing software runs well but on startup, it goes to data;. I tried to get this to start at a different url using AddArguments and StartPage but neither of these have worked. Is there a way to get this to start at a different url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated to latest Selenium.WebDriver -Version 4.0.0-alpha07, seems like all the chrome options works for chromium edge now. Hope that helps!!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'm just now revisiting this problem. The highest version I could find is alpha05. Where did you find 07?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: This does work but it's not what I'm asking about. In Chrome Driver, you're sent to data; on start up. However we can set an argument for its starting URL. For Chromium Edge, it doesn't accept any options regarding its starting URL. Instead it's just data;